# Unity 5.6 Animation doesn't restart after deactivating GameObjcet

Tags: c#, android, animation, unity-game-engine

In Unity 5.5 when I deactivate a GameObject the attached animator resets its state. But 5.6 doesn't. The Animation will continue at state which it was at before it was deactivated. Do you guys know how I can play an Animation on a GameObject which get enabled and disabled? (I only want to play the Animation once and I don't want to use a Legacy Animation)

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: try to stop the animation with `Animation.Stop()` in the same place where you deactivate the object.

Comment: @itay_421 already tried

Comment: Make sure you call it before deactivating the game object(and not after) because if the object will be deactivated the animation componnent will not be accessible.

Comment: @itay_421 No, the GameObject is already disabled and I want  to play the animation when it gets enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well known bug, try installing latest 5.6 patch it has been fixed.

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-6-0f3-some-ui-error.464224/#post-3020557

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. I solved it creating a new state with the Sprite Renderer disabled and using a bool to jump between the states. Example:

[Animator tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIczV.png)

```
this.CheckButton.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Active", false);
```

I don't need to disable the GameObject in my project, but if it's trully necessary in your project, try to jump to this new state before disable the GameObject.